# No arrow keys on Swype keyboard after updating to 4.4.2

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, swype

I updated and am now running 4.4.2, and was surprised by the update:

- The arrow keys I had now don't exist. I need them.
- Also, when it gets a word wrong, I cannot back-delete characters, it just deletes the entire word.

Is there any way out of this?

Answer (score 1):

> The arrow keys I had now don't exist.

It's probably because the update also updated the keyboard app which no longer now has arrow keys implemented. There is a way though, you can always use third-party keyboard apps from Play Store. Many do have arrow keys: [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) is an example, and [SwiftKey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey) is another example.

> Also, when it gets a word wrong, I cannot back-delete characters, it
>   just deletes the entire word.

This is because of autocorrect. You can disable it in keyboard settings by going to `Settings -> Language and Input` and check your keyboard's settings.

Comment: I got excited then... for a while.

Am reluctant to add more apps - but will give them a try.  I am appalled that good features are just thrown away though.  I can't believe it.  

I tried turning auto-correct off.  It still wont delete individual letters.  This is going to be a nightmare.  Maybe one of the alternate keyboards will work properly.  I'll try them...

Answer (score 0):

You can delete individual letters by pressing Space once and then backspaceing